# Scrollspy Highlight don't work

Tags: javascript, html, navbar, highlight, scrollspy

I'm pretty new to html and css themes. I want to create my first homepage but unfortunately it is hanging. I want to add [ScrollSpy](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp) to highlight the current section on my one-page project but it does not work and I do not know why.

I have tried everything but have not come to a solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>HTML-Projekt</title>
  
  <!-- SCRIPTS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- SCHRIFTARTEN -->
  <link href="vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!-- LINKS -->
  <link href="css/navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/sections.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
  <script src="js/smooth-scrolling.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body id="page-top" class="index" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">
    
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar">
 <!--<div class="navbar-links"><a class="navbar-links-logo" href="#page-top">Start</a></div>-->
   <ul id="topnavid" class="navbar-rechts topnav">
    <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#team">Team</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#geschichte">Geschichte</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#leere_seite">Leere Seite</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
   </ul>
    </nav>
 <header>
 <!-- BILD -->
 </header>
  
   <div id="services" class="section1">
   </div>
   
   <div id="team" class="section2">
   </div>
   
   <div id="geschichte" class="section3">
   </div>
   
   <div id="leere_seite" class="section4">
   </div>
   
   <div id="kontakt" class="section5">
   </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use:

```
<div id="services" class="section1"></div>
```

Try to change all the dividers in your HTML to something like this:

```
<div id="section1" class="services"></div>
```

Why you must use `id` and not `class` is because you can use a class multiple times, an `id` is always unique, so you need have only one `id="yourdiv"` on your page. If you use multiple `id`'s with the same value you will get a error message.

If you want to have your `services` in a `id` you can use this HTML:

```
<div id="services section1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wrap your content with a data-spy and data-target attribute, such as:

```
<div id="content" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNav">content</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks
I warapped the nav with a `<div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNav" data-offset="50">` and i changed the dividers to this: `<li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section1">Services</a></li>`
And it still don't works.
Can it be that it works, but is not properly displayed. How can i change the "highlighted" color to somthing catchy?

```html
 <body id="page-top" class="index">
    <div data-spy="scroll" data-target="#mainNav" data-offset="50">
    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar">
 <!--<div class="navbar-links"><a class="navbar-links-logo" href="#page-top">Start</a></div>-->
   <ul id="topnavid" class="navbar-rechts topnav">
    <li class="hidden"><a href="#page-top">Home</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section1">Services</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section2">Team</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section3">Geschichte</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section4">Leere Seite</a></li>
    <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#section5">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li class="icon"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a></li>
   </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
 <header>
 <!-- BILD -->
 </header>
  
   <div id="section1" class="services">
   </div>
   
   <div id="section2" class="team">
   </div>
   
   <div id="section3" class="geschichte">
   </div>
   
   <div id="section4" class="leere_seite">
   </div>
   
   <div id="section5" class="kontakt">
   </div>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is Rixcy and my answer put together, please accept one of the answers and/or upvote. You don't need to post your own full functional answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.